# Maven Build failure with Cannot find Symbol: class error

Tags: java, maven

I had a working project, when i uploaded into Github, but now when I import that into another system, it shows build failure.
The project was uploaded from Win10 and now I am importing it to Mac. It is a very basic project for Maven, and I know there is some very basic mistake that I am missing to figure.

Please find the dependencies here

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>UI</groupId>
 <artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <name>Automation</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.13.2</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <version>6.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
   <version>6.9.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

 </dependencies>
<build>
   <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
 </build>
</project>
```

After the import it is not recognizing the Hooks class that I am trying to extend to other classes too. And i get Cannot Find Symbol: Class error in the build.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/nehasingh/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/Users/nehasingh/eclipse/java-2021-032/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/nehasingh/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/Users/nehasingh/eclipse/java-2021-032/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------< UI:Automation >----------------------------
[INFO] Building Automation 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Automation ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Automation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/HomePage.java:[10,29] package UI.Automation.stepdfn does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/HomePage.java:[14,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Hooks
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/loginPage.java:[3,29] package UI.Automation.stepdfn does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/loginPage.java:[5,32] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Hooks
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/HomePage.java:[19,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable driver
  location: class UI.Automation.pageobjects.HomePage
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/HomePage.java:[32,35] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable driver
  location: class UI.Automation.pageobjects.HomePage
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/loginPage.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable driver
  location: class UI.Automation.pageobjects.loginPage
[INFO] 7 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.837 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-17T00:03:28-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project Automation: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/HomePage.java:[10,29] package UI.Automation.stepdfn does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/HomePage.java:[14,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Hooks
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/loginPage.java:[3,29] package UI.Automation.stepdfn does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/loginPage.java:[5,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Hooks
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/HomePage.java:[19,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable driver
[ERROR]   location: class UI.Automation.pageobjects.HomePage
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/HomePage.java:[32,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable driver
[ERROR]   location: class UI.Automation.pageobjects.HomePage
[ERROR] /Users/nehasingh/Downloads/AutomationUI-main/src/main/java/UI/Automation/pageobjects/loginPage.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable driver
[ERROR]   location: class UI.Automation.pageobjects.loginPage
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This was working completely fine in Win10 but not working in MacOS.

Versions:
JAVA:16
Maven: 3.8.1

Comment: Please add the pom file and error message as code in your question.

Comment: Based on the error message `package UI.Automation.stepdfn does not exist` please make sure that the UI.Automation.stepdfn package exist in your application.

Comment: As @HelloPutra pointed out, looks like you have unresolved packages and classes in your code, make sure you have imported complete project and have not missed out any manual jars added.

Comment: I have all classes and packages in the system. this project worked in Win10, this package exists